# Information about swing components (java)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jython, jcomponent

After learning python (cpython) and using [this page](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/tkinter-classes.htm) to search for tkinter widgets' options, methods and patterns, I've started to develop in jython due to javax.swing module from java which can help me make platform-independent GUIs.

My question is: is there a page like the one I mentioned above which presents the options and methods of swing objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ***is there a page like the one I mentioned above which presents the options and methods of swing objects?***

Yep (at least on a class level).

Have a look at the package summary for javax.swing (part of the API documentation):

- [Package summary: `javax.swing`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html)

Also, here is a page with screen shots of most of the standard components:

- [A Visual Guide to Swing Components](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/features/components.html)